# UC browser compatibility with semantic UI

Tags: semantic-ui

i am working with semantic ui on our webpage.but it is not compatible with Uc browser.how can i make it compatible with uc browser.on the behalf of study, semantic is not supported by UC browser.
you can test our web by http://readyviews.com.
we also used meta tags properly.applied all solution given by stack users.[enter link description here](http://readyviews.com)

Answer (score 0):

Problem is probably with UC Browser, not the SUI. There is nothing SUI is doing that could cause issues. Can you describe in detail what kind of issues are you having? And why are you using UC Browser anyway?